# Firefox - The add-on could not be installed because it appears to be corrupt

Tags: javascript, json, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-webextensions, xpi

I am trying to create an add-on for firefox which would bypass the server side authentication while logging into a website. 
However, after creating the zipped .xpi file (containing manifest.json and webrequest.js files), when I try to add it on firefox, I get the error on firefox : The add-on could not be installed because it appears to be corrupt .
I have set 'xpinstall.signatures.required' as false on firefox about:config page.[attached is the zipped .xpi file created](https://1drv.ms/u/s!AqmKJX3A9HRdarLoxJnVUE_NguQ?e=ZOZKXn)

Kindly advise on what could be the possible issue here

Answer (score 1):

The file you have uploaded has the following content:

```
FFExtn.js
FFExtn.json
```

There isnt any `manifest.json`.

Inside FFExtn.json:

```
{
    "name": "Webrequest API",
    "version": "1.0",
    "description": "Extension to handle Authentication window",
    "permissions": [
        "webRequest",
        "webRequestBlocking",
        "<all_urls>"
    ],
    "background": {
        "scripts": ["webrequest.js"]
    },
    "manifest_version": 2
}
```

There isnt any `webrequest.js`.

Change:
FFExtn.json -> manifest.json
webrequest.js -> FFExtn.js

Comment: the manifest.json file got renamed after creating the .zip file (containing manifest.json and webrequest.js files) and renamed it as .xpi file. How do I rename the .json file as suggested after creating the zip file?

Comment: Zipping does not rename files. Are you using a script to create it? You can also rename files inside the zip by opening the zip with zipping utility.